# SUM in Apache Pig

Tags: apache-pig

How could I display the SUM of the sizes for the same Classification and Type in the following example please?

`((classification,Secret),(type,Document.Office),{((size,557856))})
((classification,Secret),(type,Blog.ExternalPost),{((size,4478993))})
((classification,Secret),(type,Social.Post.Twitter),{((size,1902045))})
((classification,Secret),(type,Social.Post.Facebook),{((size,2085060)),((size,557856)),((size,1555956))})
((classification,External),(type,Blog.ExternalPost),{((size,1902045))})
((classification,External),(type,Blog.InternalPost),{((size,1438853))})
((classification,External),(type,Social.Post.Facebook),{((size,1234311)),((size,4260972))})`

This is the output from the describe function for the above relation in Pig;

`{classification: (name: chararray,value: chararray),type: (name: chararray,value: chararray),{(size: (name: chararray,value: int))}}`

I've tried the following but with no luck:

`sum = foreach groupedfinal generate $0, $1, SUM($2)`;

Error: Could not infer the matching function for org.apache.pig.builtin.SUM as multiple or none of them fit. Please use an explicit cast

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks
Mskh

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a couple of problems here.  First, the error message: this indicates that Pig cannot figure out which kind of `SUM` to compute -- whether it's summing integers, floats, etc.  The input to `SUM` should be a bag, where each tuple in the bag contains a number to be summed.  This doesn't work for you because each tuple in the bag contains another tuple.

This brings us to the second problem: your data organization.  Semantically, you really only have three fields here: `classification`, `type`, and a bag of `size`s.  But you are storing these three fields wrapped in tuples, with the name of the field duplicated as a `chararray` in the first element of each tuple.  This wastes space and makes your data much harder to process.

You can project out an individual element of a bag's tuples, like `$2.size` to get a bag of just these elements.  But in your case, this doesn't change anything because each `size` in your bag is not a number, it's another tuple, and there's no way to access this tuple's elements.

You could get around this by `FLATTEN`ing the bag, and then `FLATTEN`ing the tuple, and then re-`GROUP`ing, but I think the best solution is for you to look further upstream and restructure your data so you don't have this kind of nesting and useless fields.

Comment: Could you please tell me if there's anyway to de-reference the value field in the size tuple in the above case? When I first load the data using //LOAD 'cql://keyspacename/tablename' using CqlStorage// (data is being loaded from existing Cassandra table) the schema of the size tuple is size:(name:chararray, value:int) so I'm assuming I'll still hit a brick wall as I won't be able to extract the value field using SUM?

Comment: You can dereference the value from the tuple as `size.value`, but when those tuples are grouped inside of a bag, you're stuck.